# Complexity of n conjuction in basis {v, ¬}

Tags: logic, computational-complexity

Please, tell me how to prove that complexity of x1&x2&...&xn in basis {v,¬} = 2n. It is obvious that complexity <= 2n ¬(¬x1v¬x2v...v¬xn), but how to shom that complexity can not be less?

Comment: How do you define complexity of a formula?

Comment: It is number of operations in formula.